# Using a union with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, unions, unique-ptr

Trying to use a unique_ptr inside a union gives me a segfault when I try to std::move or std::make_unique it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

union myUnion{
    struct{std::unique_ptr<float> upFloat;}structUpFloat;
    struct{std::unique_ptr<int> upInt;}structUpInt;
    myUnion(){}
    ~myUnion(){}
};
struct myStruct{
    int x;
    myUnion num;

};
int main()
{
    myStruct aStruct, bStruct;
    aStruct.x = 1;
    bStruct.x = 2;

    auto upF = std::make_unique<float>(3.14);
    auto upI = std::make_unique<int>(3);

    aStruct.num.structUpFloat.upFloat = std::move(upF);
    bStruct.num.structUpInt.upInt = std::move(upI);

    std::cout << "aStruct float = " << *aStruct.num.structUpFloat.upFloat << std::endl;
    std::cout << "bStruct int = " << *bStruct.num.structUpInt.upInt << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, using a normal pointer works as expected:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

union myUnion{
    struct{float *pFloat;}structPFloat;
    struct{int *pInt;}structPInt;
    myUnion(){}
    ~myUnion(){}
};
struct myStruct{
    int x;
    myUnion num;

};
int main()
{
    myStruct aStruct, bStruct;
    aStruct.x = 1;
    bStruct.x = 2;

    auto upF = std::make_unique<float>(3.14);
    auto upI = std::make_unique<int>(3);

    aStruct.num.structPFloat.pFloat = upF.get();
    bStruct.num.structPInt.pInt = upI.get();

    std::cout << "aStruct float = " << *aStruct.num.structPFloat.pFloat << std::endl;
    std::cout << "bStruct int = " << *bStruct.num.structPInt.pInt << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is using clang.3.4.2 or gcc.4.9.0. So I'm assuming that I am doing something wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Ok, so it's probably a nice thing to do to share the code I settled on. Big thanks to everyone who pointed me to managing the lifetime of my pointers in variant members using placement new.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
struct myStruct
{
public:
    union
    {
        std::unique_ptr<float> upFloat;
        std::unique_ptr<int> upInt;
    };
    enum class unionType {f, i,none} type = unionType::none; // Keep it sane
    myStruct(){}
    myStruct(std::unique_ptr<float> p)
    {
        new (&upFloat) std::unique_ptr<float>{std::move(p)};
        type = unionType::f;
    }
    myStruct(std::unique_ptr<int> p)
    {
        new (&upInt) std::unique_ptr<int>{std::move(p)};
        type = unionType::i;
    }
    ~myStruct()
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case unionType::f: upFloat.~unique_ptr<float>(); break;
            case unionType::i: upInt.~unique_ptr<int>(); break;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<myStruct>> structVec;
    structVec.push_back(std::make_unique<myStruct>(std::make_unique<float>(3.14f)));
    structVec.push_back(std::make_unique<myStruct>(std::make_unique<int>(739)));
    structVec.push_back(std::make_unique<myStruct>());
    structVec.push_back(std::make_unique<myStruct>(std::make_unique<float>(8.95f)));
    structVec.push_back(std::make_unique<myStruct>(std::make_unique<int>(3)));
    structVec.push_back(std::make_unique<myStruct>());

    for(auto &a: structVec)
    {
        if(a->type == myStruct::unionType::none)
        {
            std::cout << "Struct Has Unallocated Union" << std::endl;
        }
        else if(a->type == myStruct::unionType::f)
        {
            std::cout << "Struct float = " << *a->upFloat << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Struct int = " << *a->upInt << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

Struct float = 3.14

Struct int = 739

Struct Has Unallocated Union

Struct float = 8.95

Struct int = 3

Struct Has Unallocated Union

Comment: If two pointers point to same memory cell, can they still be unique?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546706/good-debugger-tutorial-for-beginners

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Not helpful/constructive or applicable.

Comment: @Tuğrul I think only one of them exists, or at least, space for the biggest one exists. Am I missing something?

Comment: @jacksawild _'Nopt helpful/constructive'_ Why do you think so? OK, the difference is in short ownership of `std::unique_ptr` is preserved, while it's not with raw pointers. That's something that can be well achieved using a decent debugger.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: No, a debugger isn't going to help in this highly broken scenario.  The debugger doesn't track what the active member of the union is.  (In fact, just using a debugger on such a program may cause undefined behavior, because it will read from inactive union members)

Comment: @BenVoigt After reading your answer, you're probably right about this point.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: because it simply is not constructive to drop a link without being relevant.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For unrestricted union, you have to manage yourself some construct/destruction.

Following may help:

```
union myUnion{
    std::unique_ptr<float> upFloat;
    std::unique_ptr<int> upInt;

    myUnion(){ new (&upFloat) std::unique_ptr<float>{};}
    ~myUnion() {}
};

class myStruct
{
public:
    ~myStruct()
    {
        destroy();
    }

    void destroy()
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case unionType::f: num.upFloat.~unique_ptr<float>(); break;
            case unionType::i: num.upInt.~unique_ptr<int>(); break;
        }
    }

    void set(std::unique_ptr<int> p)
    {
        destroy();
        new (&num.upInt) std::unique_ptr<int>{std::move(p)};
        type = unionType::i;
    }
    void set(std::unique_ptr<float> p)
    {
        destroy();
        new (&num.upFloat) std::unique_ptr<float>{std::move(p)};
        type = unionType::f;
    }

public:
    enum class unionType {f, i} type = unionType::f; // match the default constructor of enum
    myUnion num;
};

int main()
{
    myStruct aStruct, bStruct;

    aStruct.set(std::make_unique<float>(3.14f));
    bStruct.set(std::make_unique<int>(3));

    std::cout << "aStruct float = " << *aStruct.num.upFloat << std::endl;
    std::cout << "bStruct int = " << *bStruct.num.upInt << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In C++17, you may use `std::variant` instead of your own struct

Comment: THis would be less fragile if you used an anonymous union, making the whole class a variant (union-like) class.  Right now it's possible to use the union without the wrapper that provides all the needed logic.

Answer (score 16):

Changing the active member of a union requires special care to object lifetime.  The C++ Standard says (9.5p4):

> *Note:* In general, one must use explicit destructor calls and placement new operators to change the active
>   member of a union.

When the members are plain old data, it generally "just works", even though you aren't calling constructors (using placement `new`) and destructors.  That's because the lifetime for objects with trivial initialization begins "when storage is obtained" of sufficient size and correct alignment, and the union provides that.

Now you've got members with non-trivial constructor and destructor.  Their lifetime doesn't begin when storage is obtained, you *also* have to cause initialization to finish.  And that means placement new.  Skipping destructor calls isn't safe either, you get undefined behavior if those destructors would have had side effects your program relies on (and a `unique_ptr` destructor has the side effect of deallocating its target).

Thus you are calling a move-assignment operator on a member whose lifetime hasn't begun.  That is undefined behavior.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. If I could accept two answers I would.

Answer (score 4):

From [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union):

> If a union contains a non-static data member with a non-trivial special member function (copy/move constructor, copy/move assignment, or destructor) that function is deleted by default in the union and needs to be defined explicitly by the programmer.

I assume that the reason you wrapped the pointers in simple structures is because you could not build it otherwise, due to the restrictions imposed by the above paragraph.

What you have done instead is bypassed the compilers safety-guards, and probably have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code.

Comment: Wrapping them in structs comes from the more complicated version, which I've simplified here. Removing these wrappers still results in compilable code. No by-passing here. You are right about the deleted constructors though, and by defining my own default constructor/destructor I am by-passing an error. I think the solution is somewhere in the copy/assignment/move constructor declarations which are missing, and I have been unable to figure out.

Comment: @jacksawild: Your problem doesn't have much to do with special members -- you aren't assigning the entire union anywhere.  It has to do with lifetime of the variant members.

Answer (score 3):

From §12.6.2[class.base.init]/p8 of the standard (emphasis added):

> In a non-delegating constructor, if a given non-static data member or
>   base class is not designated by a
>   *mem-initializer-id* (including the case where there is no *mem-initializer-list* because the constructor has no
>   *ctor-initializer*) and the entity is not a virtual base class of an abstract class (10.4), then
>
> - if the entity is a non-static data member that has a *brace-or-equal-initializer*, the entity is initialized as specified in 8.5;
> - **otherwise, if the entity is a variant member (9.5), no initialization is performed**;
> - [...]

Union members are variant members, which means that the `unique_ptr`s are left uninitialized. In particular, no constructor, not even the default one, is called. Technically, the lifetime of these `unique_ptr`s never even began.

The `unique_ptr` move assignment operator must delete what the `unique_ptr` is currently holding, but you are move-assigning to an uninitialized "`unique_ptr`" containing garbage values. As a result, your move assignment likely caused an attempt to delete a garbage pointer, causing a segfault.