# String not getting passed into class function

Tags: c++, vector

```
class Message {

public: 
   void changeSubject(string);
   string getSubject();

private:
   string subject;
};

void Message::changeSubject (string subjecto) //change subject{                             
subject = subjecto;
}

string Message::getSubject ()    //return subject {                                             
return subject;
}

int main () 
{
    Message person;
    string aboutwhat;
    cout << "Enter subject" << endl;
    getline(cin, aboutwhat);
    person.changeSubject(aboutwhat);

    cout << person.getSubject();

return 0;

}
```

Above isn't the full code. The problem right now is that it prints "Enter Subject" and ends the program. Why am I not prompted to cin?

Comment: An object named "person" is used in the above code snippet, yet not defined anywhere.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this after fixing the several simple compiler errors: http://ideone.com/PinsxQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code as posted has several issues and doesn't compile. The following works for me

```
// Include al necessary headers:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Either qualify the namespace of `std::string`, `std::cin`, etc
// or place a using statement like follows
using namespace std;

class Message {

public: 
   void changeSubject(string);
   string getSubject();

private:
   string subject;
};

void Message::changeSubject (string subjecto) //change subject
{  // <<< You have hidden the opening brace after the comment above
subject = subjecto;
}

string Message::getSubject ()    //return subject
{  // <<< You have hidden the opening brace after the comment above
return subject;
}

int main () 
{
    Message person;
    string aboutwhat;
    cout << "Enter subject" << endl;
    getline(cin, aboutwhat);
    person.changeSubject(aboutwhat);

    cout << person.getSubject();

return 0;

}
```

See the working sample [here](http://ideone.com/PinsxQ) please.

---

Since you have stated in your question, *"This isn't the full code"*, I'd suspect you have some error in the other parts that weren't shown.

> *"Why am I not prompted to cin?"*

One likely possibility is you have had other inputs on `cin` before, that were invalid and `cin` got into `fail()` state.
To prevent this, you can put a `cin.clear();` statement before the `getline()` call.

If you take inputs like e.g. numbers, you should check for validity like this

```
 int x;
 do {
     cout << "Enter a number please: "
     if(cin >> x) {
         break;
     }
     cout << "Not a valid number, try again." << endl;
     cin.clear();
 } while(true);
```

Comment: should I go ahead and make another question thread and post the entire program?

Comment: @Jahaha Better you step through line by line with the debugger to narrow what's the problem first.

Comment: what is this debugger program that you're talking about? (Sorry I'm fairly new to all of this)

Comment: @Jahaha See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546706/good-debugger-tutorial-for-beginners

Comment: @Jahaha I have updated my answer, with somemore information, what could cause the problem you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Since your code above looks correct.
I would suggest you first get the prompting working first.
Then add back more code later.
I just tested the following in my own environment

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

main ()
{
  std::string aboutwhat;
  std::cout << "Enter subject" << std::endl;
  std::getline (std::cin,aboutwhat);
  std::cout << "Subject: " << aboutwhat << std::endl;
  return 0;
 }
```