# Maximum width of a Binary Tree using preorder traversal

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I want to get the maximum width of a Binary tree. 
In this method using Pre-order traversal width can be calculated.
But I can't understand it properly. Please explain how the function **getMaxWidthRecur()** works.

```
// A utility function that returns maximum value in arr[] of size n
    int getMax(int arr[], int n);

/* A function that fills count array with count of nodes at every
   level of given binary tree*/

    void getMaxWidthRecur(struct node *root, int count[], int level);

// Function to get the maximum width of a binary tree
    int getMaxWidth(struct node* root){
    int h = height(root);

    // Create an array that will store count of nodes at each level
    int *count = (int *)calloc(sizeof(int), h);
    int level = 0;

    // Fill the count array using preorder traversal
    getMaxWidthRecur(root, count, level);

    // Return the maximum value from count array
    return getMax(count, h);
}

// A function that fills count array with count of nodes at every
// level of given binary tree
void getMaxWidthRecur(struct node *root, int count[], int level){
    if(root){
         count[level]++;
         getMaxWidthRecur(root->left, count, level+1);
         getMaxWidthRecur(root->right, count, level+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, what about starting up the debugger, step through the code and see yourself?

Comment: Debugging is an essential skill, you should learn as one of your first lessons. Though this question is closed, it my contain some useful information for you how to use your particular toolchain's debugger: [Good debugger tutorial for beginners](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546706/good-debugger-tutorial-for-beginners).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main work is being done in `getMaxWidthRecur`. It's initially given the parameter `level = 0`. The `level` parameter is incremented by 1 whenever we recurse down one level in the tree. The recursion will hit each node in the tree exactly once, and for each node in the tree, it increments `count[level]` by one. So when it's exhausted all nodes in the tree, `count[i]` will be equal to the width of the tree at depth `i`.

Comment: Got the logic. Well explained .

Comment: _@Synergist_ _"EDIT: not sure why this is getting downvoted..."_ Because of answering an off-topic question in 1st place. Retracted now.