# Solving ax^2+bx+c=0 equation in C

Tags: c, equation

I know that someone else has asked this question before **but** **they didn't write the program the way I do** or make the mistake I made. So here we go.

When I run the program, no matter what, it also prints out the imaginary roots.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <math.h>
  #include <windows.h>

  typedef struct tagComplex
  {
  double real;
  double imag;
  }Complex;

  void main(void)
  {
  SetConsoleTitle("Solve ax^2+bx+c=0");

  double a, b, c, delta;
  Complex x1, x2;
  char k = 'y';

  while(k == 'y')
  {
    printf("Enter the values of a, b, c: ");
    scanf("%lf%lf%lf", &a, &b, &c);
    while(getchar()!= '\n');

    delta = b*b - 4*a*c;
    if(delta > 0)                   //←-------- or delta > 1e-6 ?
    {
        x1.real = (-b + sqrt(delta))/(2*a);
        x2.real = (-b - sqrt(delta))/(2*a);

        printf("x1=%.3lf x2=%.3lf\n\n", x1.real, x2.real);
    }
    if(delta == 0)                 //←-------- or delta <= 1e-6 ? 
    {
        printf("x1=x2=%.3lf\n\n", -b/(2*a));
    }
    else
    {
       x1.real = -b/(2*a);
       x1.imag = sqrt(-delta)/(2*a);

       x2.real = -b/(2*a);
       x2.imag = -sqrt(-delta)/(2*a);

       printf("x1=%.3lf+%.3lf i x2=%.3lf+%.3lf i\n\n", x1.real, x1.imag, x2.real, x2.imag);
    }

    printf("Try another equation? (y or n)\n");
    scanf("%c", &k);
  }
}
```

**How can I fix it?**

```
Sample data: 1 -4 3

output:     
             x1=3.000 x2=1.000

             x1=2.000+-1.#IO i x2=2.000+1.#QO i

             Try another equation? (y or n)
```

Comment: Sorry this isn't an answer to your question, but the `main` function should return an `int`.

Comment: Can you edit to include an example of input, what output you think it should give, and what it actually gives? Also, have you [debugged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) ?

Comment: I READ THROUGH AND STILL DOWNVOTED :-) Whining about bullies is unlikely to endear you to us, especially since it's unlikey to be bullying at all, rather the question is deficient as it stands - you shouild have provided sample data that causes the problem. Of course, I'm treating your "I'd appreciate any help" comment as allowing us to help you better formulate questions in future.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Usually when comparing doubles you have to use an epsilon. Comparing directly with zero may give you unpredictable results. You can read more on below answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334688/how-dangerous-is-it-to-compare-floating-point-values

Comment: @Shawn No, floating point math is not to blame here.  That is the wrong duplicate.

Comment: Note in passing that `scanf("%c", &k);` is unlikely to let you go back and have another go; it will most probably read the newline after the last number, and recognize that it isn't a `'y'` and terminate the loop.  Use `scanf(" %c", &k);` with an all-important space before the `%c` to skip white space (which includes newlines).

Comment: @HenriMenke comparing a computed floating point value with `==` certainly is a problem.

Comment: @Shawn That might be true but it is nevertheless not the reason for the the bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently your branch reads

```
if(delta > 0) {
    // print two real roots
}
if(delta == 0) {
    // print single root
}
else {
    // print two complex roots
}
```

As you can see, if `delta > 0` is true, then `delta == 0` will be false, and execution will go to the else branch.  You have to make the `delta == 0` statement conditional on the `delta > 0` as well.

That is to say, replace `if(delta == 0)` with `else if(delta == 0)`.

[Live example on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JRh8SpIfkkXLrRQG)

Comment: Good answer.  So many questions on SO follow the same pattern.  I think debugging should be taught before programming.  You get given a simple program containing a bug, and you are taught how to compile it and step through execution in a debugger to find the problem.  After successfully learning that, you get to learn "hello world".

Comment: Wow yes, thanks a ton. That solves my problem. Much love from me and my program!

Comment: Oh I wasn't taught debugging but now I intend to learn it. Can I ask you guys to recommend me some tutorials?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @D.Cosmos [Good debugger tutorial for beginners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546706/good-debugger-tutorial-for-beginners).

Comment: @chux Yes, I know.  My earlier comment was just a pasted snippet.